# EternalBlue Across Networks

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability, smb

I am working on some research and I am trying to unpack exactly how NotPetya used the eternalblue vulnerability to spread across networks. My understanding of the SMBv1 Protocol is that it would not be used to communicate outside of a LAN network. I understand that many of the NotPetya victims used an infiltrated accounting software, but it seems like many were not. Based on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/188701/how-did-eternalblue-bypass-firewalls) it seems like some windows machines might keep port 445 open for SMBv1 so does this mean that any unpatched machine connected to the internet with that port open is vulnerable? Is that how notpetya infection jumped between different company LANs?

Would it make sense to block all port 445 traffic from outside of the LAN?

Most of my knowledge here comes from Sandworm and other post mortems.

Comment: It always makes sense to block port 445 traffic from outside the LAN, or even inside the LAN. Better yet, block all traffic on all ports from outside and inside the LAN, except the services that explicitly need to be accessed.

Comment: Yes @dcom-launch, of course, but I'm trying to understand how EternalBlue allows for outside spread if that is the case. Did companies leave ports open?

Comment: Why are you researching EternalBlue and not the malware that was used as a wrapper around it? If you research those, like Wannacry, then you will see how those propogated. https://www.google.com/search?q=why+did+wannacry+spread

Comment: @schroeder researching NotPetya as a case study, will update the question to be more clear

Comment: Whoops, you still have a mistake. Notpetya did not use ET to propagate. It used it to exploit the exposed system. Proagation was a different step. https://www.google.com/search?q=why+did+notpetya+spread

Comment: "does this mean that any unpatched machine connected to the internet with that port open is vulnerable?" -- why would you think otherwise?